# Weird case , how do I delete a cluster under these circumstances

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, clustering, delete

I would like to know how to delete a cluster with this type of case.

To explain, I created a cluster for two nodes and there was a bug so I had to stop the service on the first node. However after recovering the server, I can no longer see the cluster suddenly like that as if by magic in the failover manager, and when I ping the cluster is always available somewhere.

How can I delete this cluster and redo a new one? Knowing that when I try to create one,  I am told that my second server is already in a cluster while the cluster in question is no longer visible.

Windows Server 2012 R2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Remove-Cluster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/failoverclusters/remove-cluster?view=win10-ps) PowerShell command with `-Force`.